# Cómo muestro encima de la ventana un popup con el error

Tags: python, python-3.x, flet

En el programa que estoy creando con "flet" para descargar videos de youtube tengo esta función que descarga el video:

```
    def download_video(self, page):
        self.set_control_variable("URL_VIDEO", self.input_url.value)

        URL = self.get_control_variables("URL_VIDEO")
        VIDEO_LOCATION = self.get_control_variables("VIDEO_LOCATION")

        try:
            if (
                self.check_if_a_url_has_been_entered(URL)
                and self.check_if_is_url_youtube(URL)
                and self.check_if_directory_is_selected(
                    input_directory=self.input_directory,
                    page=page,
                    video_location=VIDEO_LOCATION,
                )
                and self.check_internet_connection()
                and self.check_if_the_video_is_available(URL)
            ):
                Download(
                    button_select_location=self.button_directory,
                    button_download_video=self.button_download_video,
                    button_download_audio=self.button_download_audio,
                    input_url=self.input_url,
                    download_video=False,
                )
        except Exception as exc:
            showerror("Error", str(exc))
```

Estoy usando la función "showerror" de "tkinter.messagebox" para crear un popup con el error, pero el problema que tengo es que dicho popup se queda tras la ventana de la app y lo que quiero es que se muestre encima de la ventana.

Esta es la clase principal de la app:

```
from threading import Thread
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror

import flet as ft

from app_logic.confirm_close import ConfirmClose
from app_logic.control_variables import ControlVariables
from app_logic.download import Download
from app_logic.select_directory import SelectDirectory
from app_logic.validations import Validations
from app_settings import AppSettings
from create_buttons import CreateIconButton
from create_inputs import CreateInputs
from progressbar import CreateProgressBar
from taskbar import TaskBar

class Main(AppSettings, Validations, ControlVariables):
    def __init__(self, page: ft.Page):
        AppSettings.__init__(self)
        Validations.__init__(self)
        ControlVariables.__init__(self)

        VIDEO_LOCATION = self.get_control_variables("VIDEO_LOCATION")

        # Set the window title and resize it
        page.title = self.get_config_json("WINDOW", "TITLE")
        page.window_width = self.get_config_json("WINDOW", "WIDTH")
        page.window_height = self.get_config_json("WINDOW", "HIGH")

        # Center window
        page.window_center()

        # Center elements
        page.horizontal_alignment = ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER
        page.vertical_alignment = ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER

        # Set window size
        page.window_resizable = False
        page.window_maximizable = False

        # Set user selected color theme
        page.theme_mode = page.client_storage.get("theme")

        # Window close confirmation
        page.window_prevent_close = True

        self.confirm_dialog = ConfirmClose(page)

        def __event_close_window(event):
            if event.data == "close":
                page.dialog = self.confirm_dialog
                self.confirm_dialog.open = True
                page.update()

        page.on_window_event = __event_close_window

        self.input_url = CreateInputs(
            placeholder_input=self.get_config_excel(14),
            text_size_input=20,
            keyboard_type_input=ft.KeyboardType.URL,
            text_align_input=ft.TextAlign.CENTER,
            autofocus_input=True,
        )

        self.input_directory = CreateInputs(
            placeholder_input=self.get_config_excel(15),
            text_size_input=20,
            text_align_input=ft.TextAlign.CENTER,
            read_only_input=True,
            offset_input=ft.Offset(0, 0.5),
            value_input=VIDEO_LOCATION if VIDEO_LOCATION != "" else None,
        )

        self.button_directory = CreateIconButton(
            icon_button=ft.icons.FOLDER,
            function=lambda e: SelectDirectory(
                page=page,
                confirm_dialog=self.confirm_dialog,
                input_directory=self.input_directory,
            ),
            offset_button=ft.Offset(0, 1.5),
            scale_button=2.5,
        )

        self.button_download_video = CreateIconButton(
            icon_button=ft.icons.VIDEO_FILE,
            function=lambda e: [
                Thread(target=self.download_video(page), daemon=True).start()
            ],
            offset_button=ft.Offset(-0.9, 2.5),
            scale_button=2.5,
        )

        self.button_download_audio = CreateIconButton(
            icon_button=ft.icons.AUDIO_FILE,
            function=lambda e: [
                Thread(target=self.download_audio(page), daemon=True).start()
            ],
            offset_button=ft.Offset(1, 1.3),
            scale_button=2.5,
        )

        self.progress_bar = CreateProgressBar(
            color_progressbar=self.get_config_json("COLORS", "GREEN"),
            value_progressbar=0,
            offset_progressbar=ft.Offset(0, 23),
        )

        self.taskbar = TaskBar(
            page=page,
            input_url=self.input_url,
            input_directory=self.input_directory,
            title_dialog=self.confirm_dialog.title_dialog,
            content_dialog=self.confirm_dialog.content_dialog,
            button_exit_the_app=self.confirm_dialog.button_exit_the_app,
        )

        page.add(
            self.input_url,
            self.input_directory,
            self.button_directory,
            self.button_download_video,
            self.button_download_audio,
            self.progress_bar,
            self.taskbar,
        )

    def download_video(self, page):
        self.set_control_variable("URL_VIDEO", self.input_url.value)

        URL = self.get_control_variables("URL_VIDEO")
        VIDEO_LOCATION = self.get_control_variables("VIDEO_LOCATION")

        try:
            if (
                self.check_if_a_url_has_been_entered(URL)
                and self.check_if_is_url_youtube(URL)
                and self.check_if_directory_is_selected(
                    input_directory=self.input_directory,
                    page=page,
                    video_location=VIDEO_LOCATION,
                )
                and self.check_internet_connection()
                and self.check_if_the_video_is_available(URL)
            ):
                Download(
                    button_select_location=self.button_directory,
                    button_download_video=self.button_download_video,
                    button_download_audio=self.button_download_audio,
                    input_url=self.input_url,
                    download_video=False,
                )
        except Exception as exc:
            showerror("Error", str(exc))

    def download_audio(self, page):
        self.set_control_variable("URL_VIDEO", self.input_url.value)

        URL = self.get_control_variables("URL_VIDEO")
        VIDEO_LOCATION = self.get_control_variables("VIDEO_LOCATION")

        try:
            if (
                self.check_if_a_url_has_been_entered(URL)
                and self.check_if_is_url_youtube(URL)
                and self.check_if_directory_is_selected(
                    input_directory=self.input_directory,
                    page=page,
                    video_location=VIDEO_LOCATION,
                )
                and self.check_internet_connection()
                and self.check_if_the_video_is_available(URL)
            ):
                Download(
                    button_select_location=self.button_directory,
                    button_download_video=self.button_download_video,
                    button_download_audio=self.button_download_audio,
                    input_url=self.input_url,
                    download_video=False,
                )
        except Exception as exc:
            showerror("Error", str(exc))


ft.app(target=Main)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aprueba usar [`flet.AlertDialog`](https://flet.dev/docs/controls/alertdialog) en vez de [`tkinter.messagebox.showerror`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.messagebox.html#tkinter.messagebox.showerror):

```py
dlg = ft.AlertDialog(title=ft.Text("Error"), content=str(exc))
page.dialog = dlg
dlg.open = True
page.update()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias a los dos ya se muestra encima de la ventana.

Answer (score 0):

Para mostrar el popup encima de la ventana principal de la aplicación, puede utilizar el método `Toplevel` de `tkinter` para crear una nueva ventana que se superponga a la ventana principal.

Aquí hay un ejemplo de cómo puede modificar su función `download_video` para mostrar un mensaje de error en una ventana emergente encima de la ventana principal de la aplicación:

```
from tkinter import Toplevel, messagebox

def download_video(self, page):
    self.set_control_variable("URL_VIDEO", self.input_url.value)

    URL = self.get_control_variables("URL_VIDEO")
    VIDEO_LOCATION = self.get_control_variables("VIDEO_LOCATION")

    try:
        if (
            self.check_if_a_url_has_been_entered(URL)
            and self.check_if_is_url_youtube(URL)
            and self.check_if_directory_is_selected(
                input_directory=self.input_directory,
                page=page,
                video_location=VIDEO_LOCATION,
            )
            and self.check_internet_connection()
            and self.check_if_the_video_is_available(URL)
        ):
            Download(
                button_select_location=self.button_directory,
                button_download_video=self.button_download_video,
                button_download_audio=self.button_download_audio,
                input_url=self.input_url,
                download_video=False,
            )
    except Exception as exc:
        # create a new toplevel window
        popup = Toplevel(page)
        popup.title("Error")
        popup.geometry("300x100+{}+{}".format(page.winfo_x()+50, page.winfo_y()+50))
        popup.resizable(False, False)

        # display the error message
        error_message = str(exc)
        messagebox.showerror("Error", error_message, parent=popup)

        # wait for the user to close the popup
        popup.wait_window()
```

En este ejemplo, la ventana emergente se crea con el método `Toplevel`, se le da un título y un tamaño fijo. Luego, se muestra un mensaje de error utilizando la función `messagebox.showerror` de `tkinter.messagebox`, que toma el mensaje de error como primer argumento y la ventana emergente como segundo argumento (usando el parámetro `parent`). Finalmente, la ventana emergente espera a que el usuario la cierre con el método `wait_window`.

Existe otra forma para mostrar el error encima de la ventana. En lugar de utilizar `tkinter.messagebox.showerror`, puedes utilizar `flet.AlertDialog` de la biblioteca `flet`. Este widget te permite mostrar una ventana emergente personalizada con el mensaje de error y los botones de confirmación y cancelación.

Y en tu función `download_video`, reemplaza la línea `showerror("Error", str(exc))` por las siguientes líneas de código:

```
from flet.alert_dialog import AlertDialog
alert_dialog = AlertDialog(
    title="Error",
    message=str(exc),
    on_close=lambda: None,  # Puedes agregar una función para ejecutar al cerrar el diálogo
)
alert_dialog.show()
```

Con esto, se mostrará un diálogo emergente con el mensaje de error encima de la ventana de tu aplicación. Además, puedes personalizar el mensaje y los botones del diálogo según tus necesidades.